# Basis of $L(D)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $L(D)=\{f\in k(C)\mid \text{ord}_P(f)\ge -n_p,\ \text{for all $P$ in C}\}$ be the vector space defined on page 99 of [Fulton's algebraic curves book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf).

I would like to know how to find a basis elements of this vector space. Is there any criterion to know if an element of this space is linearly independent or not?

Maybe I'm wrong, but Fulton doesn't say a word about all this.

Thanks