# what is a basis of $L(D)$? on the Riemann-Roch Theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My curiosity occured when I think about [the Riemann Roch theorem with the genus $1$ curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4544994/riemann-roch-theorem-with-genus-1-curve/4544999?noredirect=1#comment9559353_4544999). (On that post, I have asked  all functions such that $(f)+p≥0$ are constants. But, I have yet to ponder what is a basis of $\mathcal{L} (D)$ :

$$ \mathcal{L}(D):=\left\{f \in K(C) : (f) \ge -D \right\}$$
(where and $K(C)$ is a rational function field and I will put  $l(D):= \dim \mathcal{L}(D)$)

Hence, I think that it is better **what is a basis of element of $\mathcal{L}(D)$**. (of course, someone uploaded [exactly same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327539/basis-of-ld) about that, unfortunately, there is no answer about that.)

To begin with, $(\mathcal{L}(D),+,\cdot)$ is a vector space according to the textbook. $f+g$, and $cf$($c$ is scalar) is closure in $\mathcal{L}(D)$ and  I have not sincerely checked all axioms of vector space in my hand, but, at least, since such space is function space, I expect $f=\sum a_i f_i$ whose basis of $f$ is $\left\{f_1,f_2,.... f_n ...\right\}$ and since each $f_i$ lives in $K(C)$, I think that $f$ is spanned by rational functional field (and if I write $D=\sum n_p P$, the sum of number of poles and zeros in $f$ is grater than or equal to $\sum -n_p$.)

Now, based on my previous conclusion, I restrict the case with $g=1, D=P$ ( a point in $p\in C$ (where $C$ is a projective curve), then

$$\mathcal{L}(P)=\left\{ f \in K(C) : (f) = \sum_{p}\operatorname{ord}_p(f)\cdot P \ge -1\cdot P \right\} $$

To begin with, since $g=1$, by Riemann-Roch theorem, $l(P)=deg(P)=1$, hence a $\mathcal{L}(P)$ is spanned by single basis and candidator might be

$$(1)~ f=\operatorname{span}((z-z_0)^{n})(n\ge 2), ~~(2) ~f=\operatorname{span}(1),~~(3)~ f=\operatorname{span}((z-z_0)^{-1}) $$

**To begin with, is it right that I classify the case?** Once again, my question comes to *uncertainty* what is exactly what should be a basis of $\mathcal{L}(D)$.

If I am on the right track,... , both $(1)$ and $(3)$ are impossible and only $(2)$ holds. [ because the curve $C$ is a projective curve, and according to [proposition](https://youtu.be/kKS6OQUBcPI?t=836),-- the function $f$ has **no** poles, then $f$ should be constant hence $(1)$ is not the case. Meanwhile, according to the [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4544994/riemann-roch-theorem-with-genus-1-curve/4544999?noredirect=1#comment9559353_4544999) that I uploaded previously, it is impossible to have $f$ has a pole at some point $P$: When combining the previous answer with my thought, $\mathcal{L}(0)=\mathcal{L}(0\cdot P) =\left\{ f \in K(C) : (f) = \sum_{p}\operatorname{ord}_p(f)\cdot P \ge 0\cdot P \right\} = K$(constant function), with $l(0)=1$. Next, $\mathcal{L}( P) \supset \mathcal{L}(0)=\operatorname{span}(1)$. However, by Riemann-Roch theorem, $l(P)=\operatorname{deg}(1\cdot P)=1 = l(0) $, which implies $\mathcal{L}(0) \overset{linear}{\simeq}  \mathcal{L}( P) $. Hence, the case $(3)$  also impossible.(,ortherwise $l(P)$ is greater or equal to 2)